# Replace string with multiple reverse patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string that need to be replaced.

```
myString = 'I have a cat, it like food'
```

I want to replace 'cat' with 'dog', or if there's 'dog' in the string, then replace 'dog' with 'cat'.

meanwhile, I need to replace 'like' with 'love', or 'love' with 'like'.

use **OrderedDict** can set the conditions' order, but it will skip the rest of the condition if one condition meet

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
od = OrderedDict([("cat", "dog"), ("dog", "cat"), ("like ", "love"), ("love", "like")])
myString = "I have a cat, it like food"
replace_all(myString, od)
print(myString)
```

please advice.

Comment: You could use a regex that enumerates all items, then use the match as a key in a key value pair on the replacement. You'd need the lambda function in the replace. It's a simple regex `(cat|dog|like|love)`. It's probably the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Noticing your code, it appears that cat will be replaced by dog, then that dog will be replaced back to cat. This is because the replace starts at the beginning of the string each time through the loop.

Comment: Note that you want to only make a single pass through the target string, otherwise you'd just undo what you've already done. Check the python dictionary for string hash key access. That will give you the replacement value at each match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is another way of doing it

```
import re
od = OrderedDict([("cat", "dog"), ("dog", "cat"), ("like", "love"), ("love", "like")])
string = "I have a cat, it like food"
for word in re.split(", | ", string):
     if word in od:
             string = string.replace(word, od[word])
```

Comment: I love this answer among all 3 answers coz I don't have to put the string again in the code. Thanks a lot

Comment: add-on question, do you have how to Convert Pandas dataframe to OrderedDict format, so I don't have to type a string like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517059/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-ordereddict-format

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` with lambda func in replacement part. Since the replacement occurs upon every inline match, there won't be any duplicate replacements.

```
>>> s = 'I have a cat, it like food'
>>> r = [("cat", "dog"), ("dog", "cat"), ("like", "love"), ("love", "like")]
>>> dict(r)
{'like': 'love', 'cat': 'dog', 'love': 'like', 'dog': 'cat'}
>>> d = dict(r)
>>> re.sub(r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b', lambda x: d[x.group()], s)
'I have a dog, it love food'
>>>
```

Comment: there're an error NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: `s` is the original string that you want to replace

Answer (score 0):

Yet a straight forward lambda hash replacement

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> negations_dic = {"cat":"dog", "dog":"cat", "like":"love", "love":"like"}
>>> neg_pattern = re.compile(r'(?:cat|dog|like|love)')
>>>
>>> def negate_all(text):
...     return neg_pattern.sub(lambda m: negations_dic[m.group()], text)
...
>>> print ( negate_all("I have a cat, it like food") )
I have a dog, it love food
```

Comment: your answer is great but I have to put the string again in the code. Thanks anyway

Comment: @PyBoss - The dictionary is fixed, you could just dynamically join the keys if you're lazy. The alternative is to claim you can parse language words with regular expressions by using split. An utterly absurd proposition ~!