# Convert Pandas dataframe to OrderedDict format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['car','tree','love'],'b': ['bus','wood','kk']})
```

[image]

I want to convert it to a format that can be used in OrderedDict.

expected

```
OrderedDict([("car", "bus"), ("tree", "wood"), ("love ", "kk")])
```

df.to_dict doesn't work, please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try that:

```py
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(zip(df['a'], df['b']))
```